# Maximum value of $\{ i \land n \mid a \leq i \leq b \}$

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, bit-manipulation

I was doing problems in "*Leetcode*" and found a problem that I could not solve.

Given a *non-negative* number $n$ and two *non-negative* numbers $a$ and $b$, consider every number $i$ such that $a \leq i \leq b$ and among those find the *maximum* value of $n \& i$ where $\&$ means *bitwise and*.

I could only solve when $a=0$ by finding the most significant bit location  in $b$ and in $n$ and comparing both and find that $i$ should be $b$ or let location of most significant bit be $k$ from *right* then it must be $1111111.......1$ $(k-1)$ times.

But when $a \neq 0$ I am struck.  Can anybody help me?

P.S : I am finding the question and I will post it's link by tomorrow.

Comment: Where is the link to the original problem? Apparently, this is not a problem on Leetcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to reduce this to the case you already know how to solve.

If $a = b$, there is nothing to do. Otherwise, the binary expansion of $a,b$ is of the form $a = x0\alpha$ and $b = x1\beta$, where $|\alpha| = |\beta|$. If the bit of $n$ corresponding to the differing bit of $a,b$ is $0$, then the corresponding bit of $i$ should be $1$, and vice versa (more significant bits are forced to $x$).

In the first case, we are looking for a solution in the range $x10^{|\beta|}$ to $b$, which reduces to $0^{|\beta|}$ to $b$; that you already know how to solve.

In the second case, we are looking for a solution in the range $x0\alpha$ to $x01^{\alpha}$, which reduces to $\alpha$ to $1^{|\alpha|}$; that should have a solution analogous to the case you're familiar with.

Comment: But i did not understand your binary expansion ,and what is menaing of $x$ and ,why $|\alpha|=|\beta|$ ?

Comment: Perhaps an example will help. Let $a=9$ and $b=12$. Then the binary expansion of $a$ is $1001$, and that of $b$ is $1010$. In this case $x = 10$, $\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 0$.

Comment: It in answer it was mentioned that $|\alpha|=|\beta|$

Comment: Right: $|\alpha| = |\beta| = 1$. It's the length of $\alpha,\beta$ as bitstrings.

Comment: And also meaning of $x10^{|\beta|}$ ,

Comment: That's $x$ followed by $1$ followed by $|\beta|$ many $0$s. In the example above, $1010$.